# Loop through JSON file and set each value as a variable within Github Actions workflow

Tags: loops, jq, github-actions

**Goal**: set ~20 variables that are stored in a JSON file into the $GITHUBENV during GHA job.

Currently, I am hardcoding this with the parsing of the JSON file with jq:

```
- name: Set env variables from variables json
      run: |
          echo "NAME=$(jq -r '.name' variables.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AGE=$(jq -r '.age' variables.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "WEIGHT=$(jq -r '.weight' variables.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          ...etc
```

**How can I "for loop" through this process?**

Afterwards, I want to check if the variables entered manually through a workflow_dispatch run of the job match what are in the variables.json file. If they don't match, I want to update the json file with the new manually entered value:

```
- name: Set age if dispatching
      shell: bash -l {0}
      if: github.event.inputs.age != env.AGE
      run: echo "$( jq '.name = ${{github.event.inputs.age}}' variables.json )" > variables.json
```

**Similarly, how do I loop through this process?**

Comment: maybe it is easier to write an javascript action for that. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action 
jo could also use the json expression to access properties in github actions. eg: ${{fromJson(contextvar).property}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [JSON to variables](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/json-to-variables) GitHub Actions. From the doc:

<kbd>test.json</kbd>

```json
{
    "value": "value",
    "array": [
        {
            "value": "value 0"
        },
        "value 1"
    ],
    "obj": {
        "value1": "value1",
        "value2": "value2"
    }
}
```

<kbd>workflow.main</kbd>

```yaml
- name: JSON to variables
  uses: antifree/json-to-variables@v1.0.1
  with:
    filename: 'test.json'
    prefix: test
- name: Show output
  run: echo "The time was ${{ env.test_value }}, ${{ env.test_array_0_value }}, ${{ env.test_obj_value1 }}"
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Now, how about the second part of my question? What's the best way to loop through the github.event.inputs values to compare these new variables set by the json_to_variables?